# subsections of \addcontentsline{section} with wrong bookmarks

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks

I have a problem with the bookmark hierarchy after using `\addtocontents` to introduce some special lines to the table of contents. Concretely, after starring `section.2` and adding the corresponding (substitute) contents line, all the subsections of `section.2` are wrongly considered subsections of `section.1`.

After some research, I have found answers to similar problems suggesting to load the `bookmark` package (after `hyperref`, which must be loaded at the end), and adding `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection` before the `\addtocontents` line. I have tried this, but it is still not working:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\part{Parte 1}
    \section{Seccion 1}
    \lipsum{1}
        \subsection{Subseccion 1.1}
        \lipsum{1}

    \section*{Seccion 2}
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addtocontents{toc}{\string\contentsline{section}{Seccion 2}{}{section.2}}
        \subsection{Subseccion 2.1}
        \lipsum{1}
        \subsection{Subseccion 2.2}
        \lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

What I need to do to obtain a correct hierarchy of bookmarks (and correct hyperlinks) after starring `\section` and adding the corresponding `\addtocontents` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\phantomsection` command appears to be misplaced, and it is not necessary nowadays for standard sectioning commands like `\section*`. I believe the following is what you want:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\part{Parte 1}
    \section{Seccion 1}
    \lipsum{1}
        \subsection{Subseccion 1.1}
        \lipsum{1}

    \refstepcounter{section}% increase the section counter
    \section*{%
        \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\pdfbookmark[1]{Seccion 2}{section.\number\value{section}}}%
        Seccion 2}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Seccion 2}{}{section.\number\value{section}}}%

        \subsection{Subseccion 2.1}
        \lipsum{1}
        \subsection{Subseccion 2.2}
        \lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way, which dispays the page number where the unnumbered section 2 starts in the table of contents is as follows. According to your comments, this is not what you want, but I let it here in case it is useful other readers.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\part{Parte 1}
    \section{Seccion 1}
    \lipsum{1}
        \subsection{Subseccion 1.1}
        \lipsum{1}

    \refstepcounter{section}% increase the section counter
    \section*{Seccion 2}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Seccion 2}%

        \subsection{Subseccion 2.1}
        \lipsum{1}
        \subsection{Subseccion 2.2}
        \lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this correctly names the subsections of the second section, but they still appear (as bookmarks) hanging from section.1 instead of section.2 (which does not even appear as a bookmark). How can I make section.2 appear as a bookmark?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, but maybe I'm missing something. On the left part of my screeenshots, I believe that what is displayed is the bookmarks and they look quite fine to me. Did you look at it? Which PDF viewer are you using? Mine is Okular.

Comment: OK sorry, let me explain. When I adapt your code to my needs, replacing your `\addcontentsline` line by my `\addtocontents` line, I get the subsections correctly named as section2.1 and section2.2, but the corresponding bookmarks are still hanging from section.1 (probably because there is no section.2 bookmark?).

Comment: I am using `\addtocontents` instead of \addcontentsline because I need to remove the page number from section.2. Is this possible with `\addcontentsline`?

Comment: Okay, I see. Please check the updated answer with `\pdfbookmark[1]{Seccion 2}{section.\number\value{section}}`. This creates the missing bookmark when using `\addtocontents`.